# Как оптимизировать указанный jQuery код?

Tags: jquery, оптимизация

Как оптимизировать данный код, или лучше уже нельзя?

```
$('.option_dev .checkbox_dev').hide();
$('.option_dev').append('<div class="btn">Показать добавки');
$('.option_dev .btn').click(function() {
    $('.checkbox_dev').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант с привязкой обработчика клика через `on`, если это уместно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Улучшить можно**

Каждый раз вызывая что-то вроде $('.option_dev') ты заставляешь jQuery шерстить **всю** страницу в поиске всех .option_dev и делать из найденных jQuery-объект, потом вызвав например $('.option_dev .checkbox_dev') - опять весь документ будет просмотрен в поиске.

И так по начальному коду - 4 раза.

Лучше сделать так:

```
var $optionDev = $('.option_dev'); // Один раз поискали - и запомнили

$optionDev.find('.checkbox_dev').hide(); // Поискали уже в небольшом диве, а не документе
$optionDev.append('<div class="btn">Показать добавки'); // Используем сохраненное, зачем снова искать все .option_dev?

$optionDev.click(function(e) { // Опять используем сохраненное, и ловим на нем событие клика по возможно еще не существующему .btn
  if ( $(e.target).hasClass('btn') ) {
    $('.checkbox_dev').slideToggle(); 
  }
});
```

Это будет работать **быстрее**

Answer (score 3):

Если не брать во внимание `$('.checkbox_dev').slideToggle()`, то:

```js
$('.option_dev').on("click", ".btn",function() {
    $('.checkbox_dev').slideToggle();
})
.append('<div class="btn">Показать добавки') //сразу же добавляем btn
.find('.checkbox_dev').hide(); // https://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/9
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option_dev">
  <div class="checkbox_dev">checkbox</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант

```js
$('.checkbox_dev', $('.option_dev').append(
  $('<div></div>', {
    class: "btn",
    text: 'Показать добавки'
  }).click(function(e) {
    $('.checkbox_dev').hide(500);
    $(this).siblings('.checkbox_dev').slideToggle();
  })
)).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option_dev">
  <div class="checkbox_dev">
    <ol>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="option_dev">
  <div class="checkbox_dev">
    <ol>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="option_dev">
  <div class="checkbox_dev">
    <ol>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="option_dev">
  <div class="checkbox_dev">
    <ol>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
      <li>Добавка</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Логику клика можно улучшить